# installing the proper version of react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a project that contains the `Viro` package, so that package needs the `react-native` version `0.65.1` so I tried to downgrade `react-native` from `0.68.2` to the supported version of the package `0.65.1` when testing the project on expo I get this message

```
Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.65.1 for expo sdkVersion 45.0.0. Use react-native@0.68.2
Android Bundling failed 1677ms
Unable to resolve module buffer from C:\Users\MrObscure\Desktop\react\Partner\node_modules\safe-buffer\index.js: buffer could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  1 | /* eslint-disable node/no-deprecated-api */
> 2 | var buffer = require('buffer')
    |                       ^
  3 | var Buffer = buffer.Buffer
  4 |
  5 | // alternative to using Object.keys for old browsers
```

and the packages that is used in this project are

```
import React,{ useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {I18nManager, ImageBackground,Animated, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity,Image,Text,TextInput, Alert,ActivityIndicator,ToastAndroid, View } from "react-native";
import AnimatedTypeWriter from 'react-native-animated-typewriter'
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { faArrowRightArrowLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { Button,Card,Avatar,ListItem,Icon } from '@rneui/themed';
import { color } from "@rneui/base";
```

Answer (score 0):

What was the command you ran to downgrade? `npm install react-native@0.65.1` would install the specific version you are looking for. Check the pagacke.json file, what version does it say you have? Did you run an `npm i` after?

What is the expo version? You could manually in the package.json and run expo install.